# gnuplot frequency histogram in shell with only one column of information

Tags: shell, gnuplot, histogram, frequency

I want to make gnuplot with shell, i have similar code to do the whork, but i need to use only 1 column of integers to make frequency histogram.
this code puts out histogram that shows x axis every line and y axis its value, but i want to make frequency histogram for e.g. every 10 on x axis

code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#launch  make_graphs $input $output_histogram.png $output_scatterplot.png $output_stats.txt

input=$1
output_h=$2
output_s=$3
output_stats=$4
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set terminal png transparent truecolor
    set output "$output_h"
    set style data histogram
    set style histogram cluster gap 50.0
    set style fill solid border -1
    set border lc rgb "red"
    set xtics textcolor rgb "red"
    set ytics textcolor rgb "red"
    set key textcolor rgb "red"
    set xlabel "sizes" 
    set ylabel "frequencies" 
    set boxwidth 3.0
    plot "$input" using 1:xtic(2) title "seqlen frequences" ######### I need to change this line 
    set output "$output_s"
    set xlabel "sizes"
    set ylabel "frequences"
    plot "$input" smooth csplines title "seqlen frquences" 
    set print "$output_stats"
    stats "$input"
    stats "$input" 
    #print "mean: ", STATS_sumxy/STATS_sum
    #print "standart deviation: ", STATS_stddev
EOFMarker
```

input file egzample

```
12
278
99
9
219
219
164
185
164
438
438
438
438
185
164
286
286
12
12
10
10
35
35
6
6
6
```

Comment: Your question is barely understandable (actually, there is no question at all). Please correct grammar mistakes and remove all lines of code that are not necessary for your question (e.g. the tics colour). Is your problem related to implementation in bash? If not, please reduce your code to plain gnuplot syntax as part of an interactive session. There are also hints on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask